# With a dialogflow chabot, are "actions on Google" available in Slack?

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack

I did a bot that does a quiz. So far if I'm able to try talking to it through Dialogflow interface:

[image]

I need to click on `"actions on Google"`.

But I am not able to do retrieve the same answers in Slack.

I did the following:

- In the Slack app, go to the 'Bot users' section and click the 'Add a Bot User' button.
- In the Slack app ‘Basic Information’ section, copy the 'Client ID', 'Client Secret' and 'Verification Token' and paste their values into the respective fields below.
- Start the bot.
- Copy the 'OAuth URL' value below and paste it into the 'Redirect URL(s)' field from the ‘OAuth & Permissions’ section of your Slack app settings. Save URLs.
- Copy Events Request URL from the field below and paste it to Request URL in the ‘Events Subscription’ section of your Slack app.
- Enable events in the ‘Event Subscriptions’ section.
- Select necessary events in "Subscribe to Bot Events" section for example message.im, message.group, message.channel, im_created. These events will define which message types (direct, in channel, etc.) your bot will react to. Save changes. I selected `message.im`, `message.groups`, `message.channels`, `im_created`
- In the Slack app settings, go to 'Manage Distribution' and add the bot to your Slack team using the 'Add to Slack' button.

In Slack I added on the left bar Dialogflow bot.

**Are actions in Google used for a dialogflow chabot available when talking to it in Slack?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, actions on google features are not available in Slack. This is because actions on google are features are used to create a chatbot for [Google Assistant](https://developers.google.com/assistant). Each time you select Actions on Google in the chat window of Dialogflow, you preview what your conversation looks like for Google Assistant conversations.

Since you have already created a Slack bot and integrated it with your Slack channel, so you should be able to send any responses that you create in the Default or Slack tab of the responses to your bot. Just click on the + sign in the response tab and add Slack as a channel of your bot, then click on *Add Response* to start creating responses just for Slack using Dialogflows UI.

[image]

If you want to use other message types in Slack using Dialogflow, have a look at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/slack#rich). It lists how you can create Rich responses for Slack bots.

Comment: Thanks for these precisions! I tried to create some rich messages. Would you have any clue why they don't appear in Slack? I'm testing it at the moment (it's not public yet) and the rich messages don't show up. I thought it maybe needed to be public but when starting the bot I got: `Empty+team+ID+returned+from+Slack+server`

Comment: I described the problem more thoroughfully [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262287/why-would-rich-message-created-in-dialogflow-dont-appear-in-a-bot-tested-on-sla)