# Why rich message created in dialogflow wouldn't appear in a bot tested on Slack?

Tags: json, dialogflow-es, chatbot, slack, slack-api

I created two answers for the Default Welcome Intent.

One in the default one and the other as a text response which shows up in Slack and the other one using Slack as a channel of my bot, clicking on Add Response to start creating responses just for Slack using Dialogflows UI.

The second is the following, [a default template for polling from the docs](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=message&blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22*Where%20should%20we%20order%20lunch%20from%3F*%20Poll%20by%20%3CfakeLink.toUser.com%7CMark%3E%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22divider%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Asushi%3A%20*Ace%20Wasabi%20Rock-n-Roll%20Sushi%20Bar*%5CnThe%20best%20landlocked%20sushi%20restaurant.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%2C%22text%22%3A%22Vote%22%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22context%22%2C%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2Fimg%2Fblocks%2Fbkb_template_images%2Fprofile_1.png%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22Michael%20Scott%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2Fimg%2Fblocks%2Fbkb_template_images%2Fprofile_2.png%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22Dwight%20Schrute%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2Fimg%2Fblocks%2Fbkb_template_images%2Fprofile_3.png%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22Pam%20Beasely%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%2C%22text%22%3A%223%20votes%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Ahamburger%3A%20*Super%20Hungryman%20Hamburgers*%5CnOnly%20for%20the%20hungriest%20of%20the%20hungry.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%2C%22text%22%3A%22Vote%22%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22context%22%2C%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2Fimg%2Fblocks%2Fbkb_template_images%2Fprofile_4.png%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22Angela%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2Fimg%2Fblocks%2Fbkb_template_images%2Fprofile_2.png%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22Dwight%20Schrute%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%2C%22text%22%3A%222%20votes%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Aramen%3A%20*Kagawa-Ya%20Udon%20Noodle%20Shop*%5CnDo%20you%20like%20to%20shop%20for%20noodles%3F%20We%20have%20noodles.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%2C%22text%22%3A%22Vote%22%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22context%22%2C%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22No%20votes%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22divider%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22actions%22%2C%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%2C%22text%22%3A%22Add%20a%20suggestion%22%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%5D%7D%5D):

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Where should we order lunch from?* Poll by <fakeLink.toUser.com|Mark>"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":sushi: *Ace Wasabi Rock-n-Roll Sushi Bar*\nThe best landlocked sushi restaurant."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "Vote"
                },
                "value": "click_me_123"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_1.png",
                    "alt_text": "Michael Scott"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_2.png",
                    "alt_text": "Dwight Schrute"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_3.png",
                    "alt_text": "Pam Beasely"
                },
                {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "3 votes"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":hamburger: *Super Hungryman Hamburgers*\nOnly for the hungriest of the hungry."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "Vote"
                },
                "value": "click_me_123"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_4.png",
                    "alt_text": "Angela"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_2.png",
                    "alt_text": "Dwight Schrute"
                },
                {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "2 votes"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":ramen: *Kagawa-Ya Udon Noodle Shop*\nDo you like to shop for noodles? We have noodles."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "Vote"
                },
                "value": "click_me_123"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "No votes"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "emoji": true,
                        "text": "Add a suggestion"
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It should gives something like the following image when saying hi:

[image: dialog]

However if the first message shows up after launching the test in Integrations, the second never shows up, even in the little dialogbox on the right.

[image]

I thought the problem would be that I needed to make the bot public as it seems that to use rich messages, we have to copy the ‘Events Request URL' value given by Dialogflow and paste it into the 'Request URL' field from the Interactive Messages section of my Slack app settings. But the bot don't even retrieve the default message.

## Steps I followed to implement my bot

- In the Slack app, go to the 'Bot users' section and click the 'Add a Bot User' button.
- In the Slack app ‘Basic Information’ section, copy the 'Client ID', 'Client Secret' and 'Verification Token' and paste their values into the respective fields below.
- Start the bot.
- Copy the 'OAuth URL' value below and paste it into the 'Redirect URL(s)' field from the ‘OAuth & Permissions’ section of your Slack app settings. Save URLs.
- Copy Events Request URL from the field below and paste it to Request URL in the ‘Events Subscription’ section of your Slack app.
- Enable events in the ‘Event Subscriptions’ section.
- Select necessary events in "Subscribe to Bot Events" section for example message.im, message.group, message.channel, im_created. These events will define which message types (direct, in channel, etc.) your bot will react to. Save changes. I selected message.im, message.groups, message.channels, im_created
- In the Slack app settings, go to 'Manage Distribution' and add the bot to your Slack team using the 'Add to Slack' button (it bugged there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to send your desired response using custom payloads, you should first add the format required for Dialogflow to send a request to slack.

```
{
  "slack": {
    "text": "Testing custom payloads",
    "attachments": []
  }
}
```

In the attachments, add the block format and then it should send the message to your bot in slack.

[image]

The final message looks like this:

```
{
  "slack": {
    "text": "",
    "attachments": [{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Where should we order lunch from?* Poll by <fakeLink.toUser.com|Mark>"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":sushi: *Ace Wasabi Rock-n-Roll Sushi Bar*\nThe best landlocked sushi restaurant."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "Vote"
                },
                "value": "click_me_123"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_1.png",
                    "alt_text": "Michael Scott"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_2.png",
                    "alt_text": "Dwight Schrute"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_3.png",
                    "alt_text": "Pam Beasely"
                },
                {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "3 votes"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":hamburger: *Super Hungryman Hamburgers*\nOnly for the hungriest of the hungry."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "Vote"
                },
                "value": "click_me_123"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_4.png",
                    "alt_text": "Angela"
                },
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "image_url": "https://api.slack.com/img/blocks/bkb_template_images/profile_2.png",
                    "alt_text": "Dwight Schrute"
                },
                {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "2 votes"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":ramen: *Kagawa-Ya Udon Noodle Shop*\nDo you like to shop for noodles? We have noodles."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "emoji": true,
                    "text": "Vote"
                },
                "value": "click_me_123"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "No votes"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "emoji": true,
                        "text": "Add a suggestion"
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
  }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. I leave the bounty open for until Wednesday and then it will be all yours if you're still the best answer. By the way, how would you deal with the value selected?